# Ember Firebase adapter not defined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/thomasboyt/ember-firebase-adapter for my ember app,

I just created an account w firebase, and followed the steps on the wiki, but when I launch my app, this console error prevents to start the app.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined
```

If I expand the ocnsole and track the error goes to this line

```
 if (!this.url) this.url = "https://" + this.dbName + ".firebaseio.com";
    this.fb = new Firebase(this.url);
```

What Im missing ?

I set the

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.Firebase.Adapter.create({
   dbName: "I hide this value for security"
  })
});
```

And my models to

```
App.Todo =  DS.Firebase.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
```

});

Here is the load order

```
//= require ./vendor/jquery
//= require ./vendor/handlebars
//= require ./vendor/ember-latest
//= require ./vendor/ember-data-latest
//= require ./vendor/ember-firebase-adapter
```

I confirmed the DB name is hte correct one

Comment: I changed the order to load libraries and the ds bug gone, but not says Firebase is not defined

Comment: The problem is going to be related to timing and load order. With that in mind, you're going to have to, at a minimum, include the code that loads ember.js, Firebase, and firebase-adapter.js.

Comment: Add the code for load the js files